# post method not working phantomjs2

Tags: http-post, phantomjs

my header is

```
   var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

and data is

```
data = '{"mydata": "foo"}';
```

and code is

```
page.open('my site url', 'POST', data, headers, function (status) {
   var jsonSource = page.content;
   console.log(jsonSource);
   phantom.exit();
});
```

but in **onResourceRequest** my method is 'GET'
what is problem ?

Comment: Is this also the case when you check externally for example with WireShark?